# how to scrape a javascript chart while offline?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

There is this website I have access to from which I would like to parse a javascript chart. The chart is a simple time series and when I hover my mouse on one of the plot, a popup appears with the exact value of that dot.

I know where are some ways to parse these kind of charts (See [Scraping data from interactive graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571193/scraping-data-from-interactive-graph))

My issues is that I need to do it **offline**. That is, I connect to the website, and then I can only click save as html in firefox/chrome.

In this case, would the scraping be still possible with the locally downloaded page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not the data is downloaded with the page. If it is, yes, if it is not, no.

If you are just parsing an SVG graph for datapoints like in the linked question, you should be able to do it because all of the necessary data ought to be stored in the SVG.

Comment: thanks, that is actually interesting. How can I know if the data is downloaded with the page then?

Comment: I am assuming this is an SVG graph, in which case all the data you need should actually be in the SVG file.

Comment: thanks. sorry for my noobiness but where can I find the SVG file then? Which packages should I use to do that offline?

Comment: for instance, on the example shown in the link above https://opensignal.com/reports/2016/11/state-of-lte how can identify the SVG file? how can I parse it offline then?

Comment: Looking at the data in the link, the svg data is stored in a tag on the page.

It looks like they are wrapped with divs with the .js-bar-chart class.

To parse it offline you will still need a way to pull the data onto the processing site and then I would follow the steps linked in the question.